# How to use cython with python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

Hello I have this function using Python :

```
def retArray():
    return [0]*10
```

I would like to code this function using Cython so I do this :

```
cpdef int[:, :] retArray():
    return [0]*10
```

But it does not work

Could you help me please ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to declare it as returning a 2D memory view of some kind. What do you actually want it to return? Remember that as a `cpdef` function it would need to return something usable for regular (non-Cython) Python code.

Comment: What about it "does not work"?  Do you get a cython error on compilation or a python one on execution?  What is the error message?  Do you need to use a list or could an array.array or numpy.array be used instead?

Comment: Memoryviews wrap structures with the Python buffer interface. That includes the standard library `array`, and Numpy array. It does not include `list`.